# Equivalent form of derivative as limit?

Tags: limits, derivatives

I was traditionally taught the formula for the derivative to be:

$$ \dfrac{df}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$$

Is this an equally valid form? How can I see one way or the other?

$$ \dfrac{df}{dx} \overset{?}{=} \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x) - f(x - \Delta x)}{\Delta x}$$

Comment: The $\Delta x$ should tend to zero instead of $\infty$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You're correct. Bad mistake on my part.

Comment: By the way both forms are equivalent

Comment: And once that is fixed, they are equivalent, since $\Delta x$ can take positive and negative values.

Comment: To understand that these are equivalent try to understand that when $\Delta x \to 0$ then it involves both $\Delta x \to 0+$ (i.e. $\Delta x$ taking only positive values) and $\Delta x \to 0-$ (i.e. $\Delta x$ taking only negative values).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $\Delta y=-\Delta x$. Then

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x) - f(x - \Delta x)}{\Delta x}= \lim_{\Delta y \to 0} \dfrac{f(x) - f(x + \Delta y)}{-\Delta y}$$

Now move the $-$ to the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive $\infty$ expressions (Using Taylor series expansion of $f(x+h)$ around $x=x$) !!!!. For example
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\rm f}\left(x + h\right)
& = &
{\rm f}\left(x\right) + {\rm f}'\left(x\right)h + {1 \over 2}{\rm f}''\left(x\right)h^{2}
+
{1 \over 6}{\rm f}'''\left(x\right)h^{3} + \cdots
\\
{\rm f}\left(x + 2h\right)
& = &
{\rm f}\left(x\right) + 2{\rm f}'\left(x\right)h + 2{\rm f}''\left(x\right)h^{2}
-
{4 \over 3}{\rm f}'''\left(x\right)h^{3} + \cdots
\\
8{\rm f}\left(x + h\right) + {\rm f}\left(x + 2h\right)
& = &
9{\rm f}\left(x\right) + 10{\rm f}'\left(x\right)h + 6{\rm f}''\left(x\right)h^{2}
+
{\rm O}\left(h^{4}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
Then
$$
{\rm f}'\left(x\right)
=
\lim_{h \to 0}
{8{\rm f}\left(x + h\right) + {\rm f}\left(x + 2h\right) - 9{\rm f}\left(x\right)
 \over
 10 h}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This does not shed light on *what's going on* as much as the previous answer and comments, but it's worth observing that by taking either limit as the definition of the derivative, you can evaluate the other limit using L'Hospital's rule.